# How to add R squared (R^2) in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to calculate and add R^2 and R in my line chart as a legend, but I only know how to add equations in the chart. Here is my code.My English is poor,I make a mistake in the last question,I don't want to reject your approve.I'm sorry,I hope you can see this question.

---

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import numpy as np 
import pylab as pl 
y = df["rain"]  
x = df["SITE"] 
fig, ax = plt.subplots() 
ax.plot(x, y) 
ax.set(xlabel='year', ylabel='P', title='rain') 
ax.grid() 
z = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)  
p = np.poly1d(z)  
plt.plot(x,p(x), "y--") 
plt.plot(x, y, 'og-', label=("y=%.6fx+(%.6f)"%(z[0],z[1]))) 
plt.legend()
```

Comment: for square you may try r**2

Comment: Thanks for your answer,I have tried ,but how to put the r**2 as my chart's label.

Comment: may by using f string like that f'{str(r**2)}' if r is a variable

Comment: my code is    pl.plot(x, y, 'og-',label=("y=%.6fx+(%.6f)"%(z[0],z[1])),(f'{str(r**2)}'%(z[0],z[1],Rsqare)) ),but it mark positional argument follows keyword argument.What's the matter?thanks!

Comment: Were you able to run the code? I notice there are a couple of syntax and reference errors in it. Is this just a small part of your code? Could you post what's your current plot looks like? By `R`, do you mean `x` or `y` or `p(x)`?

Comment: You can also use `"r²"`.

Comment: Sorry, there is something wrong with the branch of the code. I  corrected it.I want to know how to add the fitting line of the line chart and the R ^ 2 of the fitting line as the legend in a line chart at the same time. Now I can only add the fitting line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate and plot R^2 as follows given your code:

```
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import numpy as np 
import pylab as pl 
import pylab
y = df["rain"]  
x = df["SITE"] 

z = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)  
p = np.poly1d(z)  
r_squared = r2_score(x, y)

fig, ax = plt.subplots() 
ax.plot(x, y) 
ax.set(xlabel='year', ylabel='P', title='rain') 
ax.grid() 

pylab.plot(x,p(x), "y--") 
pl.plot(x, y, 'og-', label=("y=%.6fx+(%.6f) - $R^2$=%.6f"%(z[0],z[1], r_squared))) 
pl.legend()
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did, but I found that the value of R ^ 2 is not between [- 1,1]. It's a strange number. Could you tell me the reason?Thanks!!

Comment: But when I use

    x=[1,2,3]

    y=[1,2,3]

    r2_ score(x, y)

The result is right. Is this the problem with my df function?

Comment: @chant that's why I suggest you use the function from sklearn.metrics. You will definitely get the right R squared value

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I checked the website of SkLearn. Metrics, >>> y_true = [1, 2, 3] >>> y_pred = [3, 2, 1] >>> r2_score(y_true, y_pred)=-3.0 But doesn't the R^2 of fit range [0,1]? This is just like my data, and when I apply it, R ^2 comes up with a number in the tens of thousands.But I don't know what happend in my code.Could you tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: I tried quadratic polynomial and cubic polynomial fitting, but the R-square results have not changed. They are more than - 50000. What's the problem？

Comment: between which variables do you want to find the R squared?

Comment: I want to find the R ^ 2 of X and y, but the value is unreasonable. The range of R ^ 2 should be [0,1], R_ Is the function squared not available when the difference between two variables is too large?as>>> y_true = [1, 2, 3] >>> y_pred = [3, 2, 1] >>> r2_score(y_true, y_pred)=-3.0 .What's wrong?

Comment: Please read the doc (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html): ---Best possible score is 1.0 and it can be negative (because the model can be arbitrarily worse). In your case you can -3.0 because the model is arbitrarily worse. Please accept the answer as I think I have tackled all your issues (calculating and plotting)

Comment: The r2_score from sklearn_metrics is not the one normally found in, for example, statistical analysis of experiments in manufacturing.  That value is always between [-1,1], and a good way to find it is to use scipy.stats.linregress function.  The sklearn metric r2_score may be a valid statistical measure, but it is not what most fields refer to as "R-squared", so anyone coming from a non-statistical background can easily be confused.

Answer (score 0):

You can try "$r^2$" (or any combination in a f-string). The $ renders Latex chars in matplotlib labels:

```
x = np.arange(0, 100)
y = x**2
plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
plt.plot(x, y, label="y=$x^2$")
plt.legend()
```

[image: Image illustrating Latex rendering on Matplotlib]

Comment: I've tried, it suggests ispositional argument follows keyword argument., I don't know where the problem is

Comment: @chant I have edited my answer and included one example showing the use of the $ symbol to render Latex in Matplotlib

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What I want to do is put the fitting line and R ^ 2 into the expression at the same time, not as a single legend. Maybe you misunderstood me.Thanks!!